# SwiftUI animating part of a view without affecting specific other part

Tags: swiftui

Sorry for the cryptic title.

I would like to have part of a row inside a list of rows to to animate downwards without moving the views vertically above it.

Here is a minimal example, showing what I mean:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var display = false

  var body: some View {
    List {
      Button("Toggle") {
        display.toggle()
      }
      Text("Text")
      row
      Text("Text")
    }
    .listStyle(.plain)
    .animation(.linear, value: display)
  }

  var row: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Title").bold()
      if display {
          Text("Lorem")
          Text("ipsum")
          Text("dolor")
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
      .previewDevice(.init(rawValue: "iPhone 13 mini"))
  }
}
```

The `lorem ipsum` block is supposed to animate into view without moving the `Title` text.

I imagine there's no way around `GeometryReader` here, but wanted to make sure. All suggestions are much appreciated

Comment: Can you not just move the `animation` code onto the `VStack` that contains the views you want to animate? Or even just onto the `row`?

Comment: @Fogmeister, sorry I don't see how. I tried many combinations, including the suggestion you made.

Comment: What is the effect you’re looking for? Do you want them to animate in like a drop down menu or something? Or just add them to the bottom of the list?

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, some kind of a dropdown where the text is sliding out towards the bottom.